# Oracle SQL: Counting in 4h?

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have oracle 10g database with table of many records.
Table has data for employees receiving some kind of orders.
Most usable columns are employee, dt and orderId (I've attached example).
I want to construct select that will select records of an employee that had 6 or more orders in **any** 4h. I used regular join, various functions but I still didn't made usable select.
I couldn't make select that will for each record search in past(4h) and see if there are 6 orders for same employee.

Any help or solution is appreciated.

BR,

IJ

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77418/1

Output of select should be:

Joe 19.2.2013 13:28:09  36589589

Joe 19.2.2013 13:50:59  36589593

Matt    19.2.2013 13:57:02  36589594

Joe 19.2.2013 14:19:46  36589598

Benny   19.2.2013 14:50:28  36589601

Benny   19.2.2013 14:54:58  36589602

Benny   19.2.2013 14:56:35  36589603

Ray 19.2.2013 15:26:39  36589607

Ray 19.2.2013 15:26:41  36589608

Ray 19.2.2013 15:26:44  36589609

Ray 19.2.2013 15:48:11  36589611

Benny   19.2.2013 16:48:52  36589614

Benny   19.2.2013 16:49:40  36589615

Benny   19.2.2013 16:50:38  36589616

Johnny  19.2.2013 17:37:33  36589620

Johnny  19.2.2013 17:51:41  36589621

Joe 19.2.2013 18:16:55  36589625

Johnny  19.2.2013 18:34:14  36589626

Matt    19.2.2013 21:13:50  36589632

Comment: What does "any 4h" mean? I guess not the last 4 hours but it would be better if you provided sample data.

Comment: I had picture prepared but couldn't upload it.

Comment: @ypercube: I suspect the OP wants to answer the question "Which employees had at least 6 orders between 2003-02-18 08:00 and 2003-02-18 12:00, *or* between 2003-02-18 08:01 and 2003-02-18 12:01, *or* between 2003-02-18 08:02 and 2003-02-18 12:02, ..."

Comment: I have reputation 8, and need 10 to upload pics, so sorry, as soon as I reach 10 I will upload example.

Comment: And yes if Joe had oreder received 18.2.2013 at 9:02, I want to check if he had 5 or more orders from 18.2.2013 5:02 to 18.2.2013 9:02, including this one at 9:02, that is 6 or more. Sorry, in example it is very clear.

Comment: You can add your table structure as text. The `CREATE TABLE` does not need images. Data too, with `INSERT` statements are usually more helpful than images. Even better, you can do both (structure and a few rows) at **[SQLFiddle.com](http://SQLFiddle.com)** and then post the link here, so every one can use the same table-column names and data.

Comment: @ypercube: I've created table and inserted rows on Fiddle, hope it helps to describe my problem, tnx for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `lag()` function:

```
select t.*, 
from (select t.*, lag(dt, 6) over (partition by employeeId order by dt) as ord6dt
      from t
     ) t
where dt - ord6dt < 4.0/24
```

This just looks at order 6 before the current and compares the dates.  Only rows where the difference in time is less than 4 hours are kept.

Comment: :is there a possibility to sum fields with lag function? For example: if there is another coulmn with number values near each row, e.g. 5$, and I want to say list all that are within 4h and sum(order_amount)>10$?

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it:

```
select distinct employee
  from (select employee, dt, orderid,
               (select count(*)
                    from emp_data ed2
                   where ed2.employee = ed.employee
                     and ed2.dt >= ed.dt
                     and ed2.dt <= ed.dt + (4/24)) cnt
            from emp_data ed)
 where cnt >= 6;
```

or replace `and ed2.dt <= ed.dt + (4/24)` with `and ed2.dt < ed.dt + (4/24)` if you didn't want to count say from 09:00:00 - 13:00:00 but only to 12:59:59.

Comment: I think we should stop helping if users do not post structures, data samples and desired output...

Comment: @Art: I agree, but I couldn't add picture due to reputation, so now I've created table and inserted rows on Fiddle, hope it helps to describe my problem

Comment: @Johnny - I think you already have your answers from two of the best... When posting code use ctrl+K.