# Oracle SQL: Count and sum in e.g. 4 hours?

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have one follow up question on an already solved Q ([Oracle SQL: Counting in 4h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981334/oracle-sql-counting-in-4h)).

If there is another column in data sample presented, amount column, and I want to do all the same as it is proposed in solution

```
select t.*, 
from (select t.*, lag(dt, 6) over (partition by employeeId order by dt) as ord6dt
      from t
     ) t
where dt - ord6dt < 4.0/24
```

, with one extra condition sum of amount column > 10?

So query should list only those who had 6 orders in 4 hours AND `sum(order_value)>10`.

Comment: I edited your tags. MySQL is from oracle, yes, but you don't use it (I can tell by the query syntax). Please specify which DB you're using exactly.

Comment: Did you try adding `SUM(Amount) OVER (partition by employeeid)` to your inline query?

Comment: What is 4h for crying out loud? :)

Comment: Yes, tried it just now, it sums all orders regardless if they are in 4hours time period.

Comment: Ok, sorry, it is natural to me that 4h means 4 hours, I'll rembember this for future.

Comment: I've tried adding `SUM(Amount) OVER (partition by employeeid order by dt)`, but querry sums all orders regardless of are they in 4 hour time frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution you have just looks back 6 rows (which may not be the first order that satisfied 4 hours old). So adding another analytic keeping that solution:

```
select *
from (select t1.*, lag(dt, 6) over (partition by employee order by dt) as ord6dt,
             sum(order_value) over (partition by employee order by dt rows 6 preceding) val
      from emptest t1
     ) 
where dt - ord6dt < 4.0/24
  and val >= 10;
```

would again only count 6 rows back (which may miss some real matches if we had over 6 orders in the last four hours).

we could model this instead:

```
select *
  from (select *
          from emptest
        model
        dimension by (employee, dt)
        measures (  order_value, order_id, 0 order_sum, 0 number_of_orders)
        rules (
          order_sum[any,any] = sum(order_value)[cv(employee), dt between cv(dt)-(4/24) and cv(dt)],
          number_of_orders[any,any] = count(*)[cv(employee), dt between cv(dt)-(4/24) and cv(dt)]

        ))
 where order_sum > 10
   and number_of_orders >= 6
order by employee, dt;
```

which looks for the number_of_orders at 4 or more and also checks the count over 4 hours too.

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3045d/1

Comment: second part of solution is great it gives me everything I need. But I have question regarding your comment in first sentance: _which may not be the first order that satisfied 4 hours old_, in that querry i don't want to know exact number of orders, just if currnet order (that select is checking) is 6th one in last 4hours and then mark it with dt for example. Overall it is possible that this one is actually 10th in last 4 hours, but it is also has 5 orders before...nevermind, with your second solution I get all info, tnx

Comment: Hi, again, this querry works perfectly on sample database with 10k records, but when I tried to run it on database with much more records and it runs very slow, this is normal? On which columns I should have index, on those from Dimension? Do you have any other suggestion to decrase processing time?